# Save FragmentManager isntance is good for optimisation?

Tags: java, android

Is it better for performance optimisation to store `FragmentManager` instance instead of getting all the time from SDK?

Comment: Doesn't `getFragmentManager()`/`getSupportFragmentManager()` eventually return an already stored instance?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking if getting it all the time better then store instance if have more then 6 fragments for example?

Comment: I don't see any benefit in doing so. It's not like Android reinstantiates it every time or does any other heavy-lifting in these methods. It's just a chain of getters.

Comment: I don't think any better optimization on storing FragmentManager, Calling a method of superclass won't raise the performance issue.